# Mediaelement playlist error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some problem on my mediaelement playlist, can mediaelement auto adjust height value?

I use mediaelement player (Version 2.20.1) and mediaelement playlist ([Link](https://github.com/duozersk/mep-feature-playlist)) , I got this problem:
when I open the playlist, player's height value can't auto adjust,this problem will cover my footer...
**UPDATE**

Solved !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the place to fix it :
Use js

```
jQuery(".mejs-hide-playlist, .mejs-show-playlist").click(function () {
    if (jQuery(".mejs-playlist").is(":visible")) {
        jQuery('#footer').css('margin-top', jQuery(".mejs-playlist").height() + 20);
    }
    else {
        jQuery('#footer').css('margin-top', 0);
    }
});
jQuery('#footer').css('margin-top', jQuery(".mejs-playlist").height() + 20);
```